# Navigate from parent to child in react where each component defines its own routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In a React app with a parent and child elements, I want to achieve the following when navigating to `/Parent/Child`:

1. I want `Child` to be rendered *on a new page*.
2. I want to *avoid* defining a route for `/Parent/Child` in `index.js` (the topmost file).

Currently, in the following code ([see it live](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-sea-yhtnj)), when navigating to `/Parent/Child`, both parent and child are rendered, thus breaking requirement #1. The reason is that `<Route path='/Parent' component={Parent} />` doesn't have the `exact` attribute.

However, making it `<Route exact path='/Parent' component={Parent} />` won't work as well, since `Child` won't be rendered at all ([see it live](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lake-pt2m1)), which I understand why.

An optional solution is to add `/Parent/Child` route in `index.js` (and also get rid of the `Route` in `Parent`, [see it live](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-ishizaka-7nkjj)), but it breaks requirement #2.

So, is it possible to achieve both requirements? if so, how?

- React version is 17, react-router-dom version is 5.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Parent from './Parent';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/Parent' component={Parent} />
      </Switch>
      <Redirect from='/' to="/Parent" />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode >,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Parent.js**

```
import Child from './Child';
import { Route, useRouteMatch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function Parent() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/Child`} component={Child} />
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <a target="_blank" onClick={() => history.push(`${match.path}/Child`)}>Navigate To Child</a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

**Child.js**

```
import BackButton from './BackButton';

function Child() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Child</h1>
      <BackButton>Go Back</BackButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child;
```

**BackButton.js**

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function BackButton({ children }) {
  let history = useHistory()
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => history.goBack()}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
export default BackButton;
```

Comment: since you want it in a different window, you can't use history.push here. Just make it an old-school link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the `Parent` as an "index" page. Using another `Switch` you can render "child of" routes and a default fallback route. This takes advantage of the `Switch` component's matching and rendering only a single `Route` or `Redirect` component.

```
function Parent() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}/Child`} component={Child} />
        <Route>
          <h1>Parent</h1>
          <a
            target="_blank"
            onClick={() => history.push(`${match.path}/Child`)}
          >
            Navigate To Child
          </a>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit navigate-from-parent-to-child-in-react-where-each-component-defines-its-own-rout]

Comment: I may have not understood it correctly, but is using the second `Route` this way an acceptable practice? I mean, it doesn't define a `path`. Well, It sure does the work! but I wonder if that's a good way to go.

Comment: @OfirD Sure. A route with no path will match any path. Think of it as something like `path={\`${match.path}\`}` or `path="*"`.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I just tried to take your last comment and see what happens if we take the `<h1>` and the `<a>` outside of their container `Route`. The result is that parent and child are rendered on the same page. So it seems that nesting the `<h1>` and `<a>` under the `Route` is an essential part of making it work? But why (I thought adding the switch and the additional "general" Route is what made it work)?

Comment: @OfirD When I do that the pages appear to fail to even load, but if I place them in a `div` it still works. Really, only `Route` and `Redirect` components are valid children of `Switch` components. [Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

Comment: If it helps, [here is what I referred to in my last comment](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-keldysh-077xb). Do you have an idea why both parent and child renders on the same page, while your solution works?

Comment: @OfirD Oh that's easy, the header and anchor tag are *outside* the `Switch` and `Parent` will render all its JSX, unconditionally. The `Switch` is what conditionally renders matching routes.